# speed up time for loop iterations in python

Tags: python, numpy, performance, for-loop

I have "random" points and would like to check which points can be connected by straight lines. Therefore I iterate through a list of points and draw a line at different angles. After all lines at all angles for every single point is drawn, I iterate over each line checking whether they are connecting 3 or more points. If the line connects 3 or more points, it is saved by appending it to a new list (`newLines`), if not the next line gets tested.

The problem which the following code is that it is way to slow... My testing image took about 30 min and my actual image was not done after about 14 hours. I read about speeding up for loops by using numpy (like in [this article](https://python.plainenglish.io/python-how-to-replace-python-for-loops-with-numpy-operations-a12b75fc2d57)). I found plenty of examples for replacing `for loops` with `numpy` but in these example it was just simple iterating over a list without declaring the values as variables for usage.

Any hint for speeding up the following code is appreciated, it does not necessarily need to be numpy.

```
# list for saving rotated lines
lines=[]

for point in points:
    # length of line is the diagonal of the point image so it still covers the whole image after rotation
    length = sqrt(image.shape[0]**2+image.shape[1]**2)
    start = Point(point)
    end = Point(start.x+length, start.y)
    line = LineString([start,end])
    # rotating the generated line for 5 degrees and appeding it to the list
    for a in range(0, 360, 5):
        angle = np.deg2rad(a)
        line = rotate(line, angle, origin=start, use_radians=True)
        lines.append(line)

multiLines = MultiLineString(lines)

# list for rotated lines which connect 3 or more points
newLines = []
start = ()

for multiLine in multiLines.geoms:
    lst = list(multiLine.coords)
    # a: starting point of line | b: ending point of line
    a = np.asarray(lst[0])
    b = np.asarray(lst[1])
    count = 0
    # again iterating over point array to check which point is on line
    for point in points:
        p = np.asarray(point)
        # check if point (p) is on line (a - b)
        if np.cross(p-a,b-a) == 0:
            if count == 0:
                start = point
                count += 1
            else:
                end = point
                count += 1
    if count >= 3:
        line = (start, end)
        newLines.append(line)
```

Comment: Without looking at the code I would say the problem is not using more advanced tools like numpy but instead considering the time complexity of your code and how it scales. If you have written an algorithm that is exponential in n you are expected to run into problems very quickly with even small n. How many points are you dealing with? Assuming 1000 points you have 360000 lines and then 360000000 line-point comparisons.

Comment: Simple improvement might be to break the inner loop if you reach a count of 3

Comment: Is there another approach possible (none exponential)? I tried using numpy but with my current skills I find it hard using abstract approaches... Are there other tools with a "more straight forward" usage?

Comment: Couple of minor points.. No need to calculate *length* for every *point*. Do it once outside the loop. Also outside of that loop build a list of *np.deg2rad()* then iterate over that rather than recalculating. The magnitude of your problem must be related to the number of *points* and *multiLines.geoms*. What kind of figures are you dealing with. Billions?

Comment: @luk2302 but if I break the loop at count of 3, I don't get the full extents of the line. But maybe if I iterate the array "form the back".

Comment: @OldBill good point! The testing image, which takes about 30 min, has just about 240 points... The whole image should be around low 4 digits

Comment: @jonsken What does *rotate()* do? (I know nothing about image processing)

Comment: *"if I break the loop at count of 3, I don't get the full extents of the line"* - neither does that happen if you keep going since your points cannot be sorted in a way that you always check the points furthest away from your start point last.

Comment: @OldBill *rotate ()* rotates the previous created line for every angle (~~~a~~~) in ~~~range(0, 360, 5)~~~. Basically just routing the line at 5 degrees and then adding to the new list

Comment: @jonsken It's the implementation of *rotate()* that might be interesting. Have you tried profiling the code to see where all the time's being spent?

Comment: @OldBill _profiling_ by just logging the time or is there an actual tool?

Comment: @jonsken Take a look at the cProfile module

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your current benchmarks are, but you want to try with numpy you can do something like this. I'm using pandas which is a numpy wrapper, but it's effectively doing the same thing

I think this is doing the same thing as you want. I'm looking at each pair of points, calculating the `m` and `c` coefficients in the equation `y = mx + c` through the two points, then checking for cases where these match. I expect you might want some accepted error depending on your input data.

Sorry if I'm way off piste.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import itertools
import time

def get_matches(points):
    # get all combinations of two points
    combinations_of_points = ([(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1]) for a, b in itertools.combinations(points, 2) if a != b])

    data = pd.DataFrame(combinations_of_points, columns=['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'])

    data['m'] = (data.y1 - data.y2) / (data.x1 - data.x2)

    # swap negative gradients so all lines are in same direction
    data.loc[np.isfinite(data.m) & data.m < 0, 'm'] = -(1 / data.m)
    data.loc[np.isneginf(data.m), 'm'] = -data.m

    # y = mx + c
    data['c'] = data.y1 - (data.m * data.x1)

    data = data.sort_values(['m', 'c', 'x1']).reset_index(drop=True)

    # filter to items which are duplicated
    filtered = data[
        # matching m and c values
        (np.isfinite(data.m) & data.duplicated(['m', 'c'], keep=False)) |
        # infinite m and x equal (straight line up)
        (np.isposinf(data.m) & data.duplicated(['m', 'x1'], keep=False))
    ]
    return filtered

points = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
print(get_matches(points))

random.seed(1)
count = 500
random_points = [(round(random.random(), 3), round(random.random(), 3)) for i in range(count)]
results = get_matches(random_points)
print(results)

print('\nPerformance with increasing points')
for i in [i ** 2 for i in range(5, 101, 5)]:
    random.seed(1)
    random_points = [(round(random.random(), 3), round(random.random(), 3)) for i in range(i)]
    start = time.perf_counter()
    results = get_matches(random_points)
    stop = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'{i:<9}{stop - start:03f}')
```

returns:

```
   x1  y1  x2  y2    m    c
0   0   0   1   1  1.0  0.0
1   0   0   2   2  1.0  0.0
2   1   1   2   2  1.0  0.0
           x1     y1     x2     y2    m      c
12243   0.606  0.262  0.400  0.880 -3.0  2.080
12244   0.606  0.262  0.440  0.760 -3.0  2.080
12251   0.378  0.970  0.506  0.586 -3.0  2.104
12252   0.505  0.589  0.378  0.970 -3.0  2.104
12253   0.505  0.589  0.506  0.586 -3.0  2.104
...       ...    ...    ...    ...  ...    ...
124741  0.971  0.382  0.971  0.716  inf   -inf
124742  0.971  0.543  0.971  0.716  inf   -inf
124744  0.983  0.593  0.983  0.296  inf   -inf
124745  0.983  0.593  0.983  0.448  inf   -inf
124746  0.983  0.296  0.983  0.448  inf   -inf

[237 rows x 6 columns]

Performance with increasing points
25       0.010577
100      0.016897
225      0.045443
400      0.136834
625      0.338148
900      0.765913
1225     1.525819
1600     2.645753
2025     4.834811
2500     8.112012
3025     12.960043
3600     18.262522
4225     27.221498
4900     37.329662
5625     53.064736
6400     67.325213
7225     84.843119
8100     116.864120
9025     140.131420
10000    171.630961
```

As one of you comments pointed out earlier, the order of growth of the problem is approximately N ^ 2 because it is look at [all the combinations of points](http://log.manl.io/cs/compute-the-order-of-growth-of-a-program/) so the performance very quickly degrades with increasing numbers of points. Note you could use this relationship to estimate how long it would take for your program to run if you know the number of points.

[image: Performance graph vs. n^2 prediction]